# Group Policy for Multiple SNMP Permitted Managers

Tags: windows, group-policy, snmp, windows-registry

I have a group policy to add the IP of a permitted SNMP Manager:
[image]

How would I alter this to add additional permitted managers (More IPs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a policy setting for this under Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Network --> SNMP --> Permitted Managers.  You don't need to modify the registry directly.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah, perfect example of how I can probably figure this out on my own (See my own answer to this question) -- but by asking I get a *better* answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I see now, Value name is each entry.

So add "3" for the next one with the data being the Ip.